# Logic Apps Office 365 connector how to send plain/text email

Tags: azure-logic-apps, microsoft-graph-mail, office365connectors

How can I set the content type of the email body in the activity Send Email(v2) in O365 connector in logic apps? The default is html and I cannot see an option to change it

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you cannot change the content type of the body since Microsoft Office 365 is a cloud-based service connector and retrieves or send the email in the underlying HTML type. However, while sending any email you don't have to include any HTML elements in the body.

[image]

**In the inbox**

[image]